# (UPDATE) JAVA: Adding the quantity of a data in table column

Tags: java

Im trying to update my quantity column but it gives me error..

here's my code:

```
private void BtnPurchsPurchaseRunningOutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                            
        try{
            String upd = "update for_purchaseitems set Quantity=Quantity+? where Description=?;";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(upd);
            pst.executeUpdate(upd);
            if(rs.next()){
            pst.setString(1, txt_PurchsQty.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txt_PurchsDesc.getText());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "success!");
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        Updatefor_PurchaseItem();
        BtnPurchsPurchaseRunningOut.setVisible(false);
        BtnPurchsPurchase.setVisible(true);
    }
```

the error message says:

you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'? where Description=?' at line 1

Comment: It says:
you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'? where Description=?' at line 1

Comment: To improve your question, use the "edit" link under the question, rather than comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `executeUpdate` *before* you've set your parameters; so the statement ends up having *literal* `?` rather than your parameters. The sequence you want is:

- Create the statement
- Set its parameters
- Execute it
- Read the results

So:

```
pst=conn.prepareStatement(upd);
pst.setString(1, txt_PurchsQty.getText());  // Before
pst.setString(2, txt_PurchsDesc.getText()); // Before
pst.executeUpdate(upd);                     // After
if(rs.next()){
```

Also note the `;` after `pst.setString(2, txt_PurchsDesc.getText())`, which was missing in the question.

---

If `quantity` is a *numeric* column, as the `+` and name suggest, don't use `setString`, either; use `setInt` or `setLong`:

```
pst=conn.prepareStatement(upd);
pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txt_PurchsQty.getText())); // <===
pst.setString(2, txt_PurchsDesc.getText());
pst.executeUpdate(upd);
if(rs.next()){
```

---

Separately: Many JDBC providers are fine with it, but you don't need or want that `;` at the end of the statement and can/should remove it.

```
String upd = "update for_purchaseitems set Quantity=Quantity+? where Description=?;";
// Here --------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: thanks! I already did this but still has the same error... T.T

Comment: @DjayPediA: It was definitely *one* of the problems. I just noticed you're using `setString` with what's likely to be a numeric column. See the update.

Comment: uhmm... should I change it? I already allocated the datatype of quantity into nvarchar... I thought it would be easy if the front-end will be the one to restrict this data types... ugh! im doomed..

Comment: THERE!! I GOT IT!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! WOOOO!!!! Thanks Mr.Crowder @T.J.Crowder